# Prevent non-root users from viewing /var/www

Tags: permissions, apache2

Is there a way to prevent users from viewing /var/www?

I tried chmod 0750 on /var/www, however, that prevented the webserver from viewing the files as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that apache user needs access.

IMO ...

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www
```

Your permissions of 750 should then work.

With that said, sort of silly as users can still see the data via a web browser ( http: //localhost ) So be sure to password protect the data from apache ...

Comment: The reason I have it like that is I have some php files which contain hardcoded passwords that I do not want other users to see.

Comment: OK, makes sense

Comment: @user1772510 you shouldn't use hardcoded password in "visible" php files. Somebody could `http://yourserver.com/php/hardcoded_pw.php` and read them either way.